# .net framework 4.7 force secure authorization cookies

Tags: .net, vb.net, cookies

I need a way to force the `Secure` flag on the `.ASPXANONYMOUS` and `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` cookies on our site.

Locally, just setting the web config values (`requireSsl="true"`) in their appropriate places works fine.

The problem arises in our production environment, which is behind a proxy. The connection to the proxy is secure, but between the proxy and the application is not, so the application doesn't see the request as secure, which means it won't set the `Secure` flag on the authorization cookies.

I would like a solution like [this one](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/securing-authentication-cookies-in-asp-net-core) but for .net framework 4.7. This looks like it would work for us, if I could find the configuration, but we're not running .net Core yet.

So does anyone know how/where I can set something similar in framework 4.7?

**Note**
I've tried looping through the cookies on `RequestEnd`, and setting the secure flag, but that seems to break the two cookies in question entirely.

Considering [this option](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/haproxy_intercept_all_cookies_and_set_secure_attribute.html) in the haproxy, but would honestly prefer a project solution if there is one.